# Problems installing SearchApp

Tags: javascript, cloudant

**Prolem:**

I have a cloudant account. I also tried to install the following app:
[SearchApp](https://github.com/cloudant/SearchApp)
Everything works, install completes as it should be but when I access the site I can't search for anything.

**Question**

I says the following at the link: *By default, searches are executed against the field "all".* I don't have any response when I use the app provided search engine.

**[Update]**

There is no error output anythin. It also says that i should index what I want, but I don't find a clue how to do it. In my cloudant database I can do this with javascript functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SearchApp code was out of date and relied on an old version of Cloudant Search. I've updated the application in GitHub to use the new Search API so it should work after you pull those changes.